# Passing parameters from android in php fail

Tags: php, android, html

I want to send some parameters from Android into PHP, but I can't understand that where is the problem in my code, it send Error in PHP that don't know the values. Here is my Java code:

```
try{
    String data=URLEncoder.encode("lat","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode( Lat,"UTF8");
             data+="&"+ URLEncoder.encode("lng","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode( Lng,"UTF8");
             data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("radius","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode( Radius,"UTF8");

    URL mylink=new URL(Link);
    URLConnection connect=mylink.openConnection();

    connect.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr=new OutputStreamWriter( connect.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()) );
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    String line="";
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        sb.append(line);

    }

    MainActivity.res=sb.toString();

}catch(Exception e){

}
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<html>
<head>
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="test"></p>

<?php
$lat=$_POST['lat'];
$lat=$_POST['lng'];
$radius=$_POST['radius'];

?>
```

Can you help me with my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: What error getting in PHP?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Notice: Undefined index lat , as i saied , it does not know the parameters .

Comment: No need to encode parameter names just encode parameter values.like: use `"lat="` instead of `URLEncoder.encode("lat","UTF8")`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it did not work :(

Comment: Tried echoing `$_GET['lat']` in php?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes still not working :(

Comment: connect.setRequestMethod("POST");

Comment: HttpUrlConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) myLink.openConnection();

Comment: @greenapps doesnt have this method : setRequestmethod

Comment: HttpUrlConnection does.